# jqplot bar chart point label font size

Tags: jqplot

I have a horizontal barchart. I am able to set axes' font size but not the pointlabel's. How can one achieve that?

thanks

```
var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart2', [values], {
                seriesDefaults: {
                    renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                    rendererOptions: {
                        barDirection: 'horizontal',                                     
                        barPadding: 40,
                        barMargin: 40,
                        barWidth: 10
                    }, 
                    pointLabels: { 
                        show: true, location: 'e', edgeTolerance: -15, formatString: '%s'
                    }
                },
                axes: {
                    xaxis: {                                                        
                        tickOptions: {
                            fontSize: '30pt'
                        }                           
                    }, 
                    yaxis: {
                        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,

                        tickOptions: {
                            fontSize: '30pt'                                
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're using the [pointLabels plugin](http://www.jqplot.com/examples/point-labels.php) you need to style the labels with CSS. You could add the following CSS:

```
#chart1 .jqplot-point-label {
  font-size: 30pt;
}
```

where `chart1` is the ID of the chart. This sets the point labels `font-size` to 30pt.

Please see [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zwtv5scL/) for a working demo.